# Satisfiability of Divisible Group Axioms

Tags: group-theory, logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I'm struggling with this problem:

> Let $\mathcal{G}=(G,+,-,0)$ be an abelian group. Work in the language $L=\{+,-,c_0\}$ and expand it with a constant symbol $c_g$, for each $g\in G\setminus \{0\}$. Let $\Sigma$ be the set of divisble group axioms and let:
>
> $$\Sigma' = \Sigma \cup\{c_{g_1}+c_{g_2}=c_h: g_1,g_2,h\in G \text{ and } g_1+g_2=h\} \cup \{c_g\neq c_h: g,h\in G \text{ and } g\neq h\}$$
>
> (a) Prove that $\Sigma'$ is satisfiable;
> (b) Conclude that, up to isomorphism, every abelian group $\mathcal{G}$ embeds into some divisible abelian group $\mathcal{H}$.
> (c) Show that, if $\mathcal{G}$ is infinite, there exists $\mathcal{H}$ as in (b) such that $|G|=|H|$.

Now I have problems with point (a), I can't manage to prove the satisfiability of $\Sigma'$.

I posted also points (b), (c) because I get the idea but I'm struggling to formalize it. Any help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: This is the standard fact that every module embeds in an injective module together with the description of the injective abelian groups as being the divisible ones. Not really logic but module theory.

Answer (score 3):

First show that every **finitely generated** abelian group can be embedded in a divisible one. This uses the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups plus the divisibility of $\mathbb Q$, $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$, and direct sums of copies of these. This result for finitely generated abelian groups gives you that every finite subset of $\Sigma'$ is satisfiable. Apply the compactness theorem.